# iOS. How to not put the same code into three ViewControllers that do almost the same

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a really simple **Concentration** game and got a question.

I have a `ViewController` where users can pick difficulty level(easy, normal hard). Then, there are 3 more `ViewControllers`, each `ViewController` is a new level. The game logic works pretty much the same, only some minor things should be changed. I could just copy and paste the same code into all three controllers and that doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Can I avoid this somehow? Maybe I don't even need 3 `ViewControllers`, but this is my first app ever and my knowledge is miserable.

Comment: Classic problem.  The battle between duplication vs reusability.  It's up to you, the developer, to determine what feels best (no one size fits all solution here).  You can use 1 VC with different modes/states and add the appropriate if/else checks. But do this too much and you are creating a god object.  Other alternatives are to use a base VC (that they all inherit from) and put only the shared code in it. Again leading you towards a God object.  Finally, use a level of abstraction using something like VIPER or MVVM and feed your TV only basic data (ViewItems or Entities).

Comment: create base viewController class and derived your vc class from that and where need override the methods

Comment: It’s easier to help if you show the actual code.

Comment: You can use MVVM pattern . Making a view model makes more resuability

Answer (score 1):

Create one enum in common viewController class and pass that enum value according to your requirement and you can vary the code according to that enum value in common viewController

```
    enum GameLevel {
      case easy, normal, hard
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create protocols and use those in view controllers.

https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/protocol-in-swift-with-practical-examples-8b955268ce39

Answer (score 0):

I think you choose protocol oriented programming here, Now Apple prefers Protocol oriented programming in the development.

**Tips:**

- You can create a protocol with the required methods which can be used in different controllers.
- You can create separate Modal for the data which is common in all 3 view controllers.
- Even I suggest you to go with some architecture like MVVM/VIP + coordinator which can be useful over here(This is optional if you are a beginner)

**Benefits:**

- Your code will be managed.
- You will learn a very handy concept of protocol oriented programming.
- If you have a time and you want to explore different architecture then it is really good to go with MVVM.